# How to combine multiple columns into one and omit 0s?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame (please note that the column names are the same as the non-zero observations within them):

```
Name          L3      L2     R2
Joe           0       L2     0
Alex          L3      0      R2
Jim           0       0      0
Eric          0       L2     R2
Brian         L3      L2     R2
```

I would like to combine the second through fourth columns into a single column that separates the observations with a dash and omits 0s.

```
Name          L3      L2     R2      new
Joe           0       L2     0       L2
Alex          L3      0      R2      L3-R2
Jim           0       0      0       0
Eric          0       L2     R2      L2-R2
Brian         L3      L2     R2      L3-L2-R2
```

I have tried the following command:

```
df$new<- with(df, paste0(L3, L2, R2))
```

But that does not separate with a dash and includes 0s. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the 0 values to `NA` and then use `tidyr::unite` to combine columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-1, na_if, 0)) %>%
  tidyr::unite(new, L3:R2, na.rm = TRUE, sep = '-', remove = FALSE)

#   Name      new   L3   L2   R2
#1   Joe       L2 <NA>   L2 <NA>
#2  Alex    L3-R2   L3 <NA>   R2
#3   Jim          <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4  Eric    L2-R2 <NA>   L2   R2
#5 Brian L3-L2-R2   L3   L2   R2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `base R` solution with `apply()`. The build-in function `myfun` detects the positions with non-zero and then combines with `paste0()`. Some adjustment with `if()`is done for adding the zero in all rows with zeros. Here the code:

```
#Code
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- paste0(names(x)[x!=0],collapse = '-')
  if(y=='') {y=0}
  return(y)
}
#Apply
df$Var <- apply(df[,-1],1,myfun )
```

Output:

```
df
   Name L3 L2 R2      Var
1   Joe  0 L2  0       L2
2  Alex L3  0 R2    L3-R2
3   Jim  0  0  0        0
4  Eric  0 L2 R2    L2-R2
5 Brian L3 L2 R2 L3-L2-R2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Alex", "Jim", "Eric", "Brian"
), L3 = c("0", "L3", "0", "0", "L3"), L2 = c("L2", "0", "0", 
"L2", "L2"), R2 = c("0", "R2", "0", "R2", "R2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

`paste0()` did not include the dashes because you didn't specify them. That's a relatively simple fix:

`paste0(L3, "-", L2, "-", R2)`

But Duck beat me to the entire solution, and theirs works.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package.

```
> df %>% rowwise() %>% 
+   mutate(new = toString(na.omit(c_across(2:4)))) %>% 
+   mutate(new = str_extract_all(new, '[A-Z][0-9]')) %>% 
+   unnest(new, keep_empty = T) %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(new = paste0(new, collapse = '-')) %>% distinct() %>% 
+   mutate(new = case_when(new == 'NA' ~ '0', TRUE ~ new))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Name [5]
  Name  L3    L2    R2    new     
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
1 Joe   0     L2    0     L2      
2 Alex  L3    0     R2    L3-R2   
3 Jim   0     0     0     0       
4 Eric  0     L2    R2    L2-R2   
5 Brian L3    L2    R2    L3-L2-R2
>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `do.call` with `paste` in `base R`

```
df$Var <- gsub("^-|-$|(?<=-)-", "", do.call(paste,
      c(replace(df[-1], df[-1] == 0, ""), sep="-")), perl = TRUE)
df$Var[!nzchar(df$Var)] <- '0'
```

-output

```
df
#   Name L3 L2 R2      Var
#1   Joe  0 L2  0       L2
#2  Alex L3  0 R2    L3-R2
#3   Jim  0  0  0        0
#4  Eric  0 L2 R2    L2-R2
#5 Brian L3 L2 R2 L3-L2-R2
```